# How to set the result of File.ReadAllLines to ResizeArray or Array in f#?

Tags: f#

I have this prog:

```
let mutable lines=new ResizeArray<string>()

let paramLines=
 if File.Exists(maincfPath) then
   lines=File.ReadAllLines(maincfPath)
 else
   Environment.Exit(0)
```

the type of File.ReadAllLines is string[],If I use Array.zeroCreate,I have to decide a initial num,but I have not use File.ReadAllLines,so I don't know the num.If I use ResizeArray,It's type is ResizeArray,I can't pass string[] to it.

How to slove this problem?Thanks!

Comment: "mutable" doesn't mean that the object to which the `lines` variable refers can be mutated; it can be mutated no matter what.  Rather, `mutable` means that the `lines` reference itself can be reassigned to point to an entirely different object, which is what you seem to want to do.  But that's not actually happening in your code, because `lines = File.ReadAllLines(maincfPath)` is an equality test, not an assignment.  You want `lines <- File.ReadAllLines(maincfPath)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No need to declare or initialize a mutable array. Just use `let` to bind a name to the result of `ReadAllLines`

```
if File.Exists(maincfPath) then
   let lines = File.ReadAllLines(maincfPath)
   ... // do something with lines
else
   Environment.Exit(0)
```

when handling errors, I prefer using `if` `then` `else` this way, which avoids the arrow pattern:

```
 if File.Exists(maincfPath) |> not then Environment.Exit(0) else
 let lines = File.ReadAllLines(maincfPath)
 ... // do something with lines
```

Answer (score 2):

You can just use the empty array `[||]`, as that will be replaced anyway with the array that `File.ReadAllLines()` creates.

Answer (score 0):

If possible please avoid reading ALL Lines into memory with `ReadAllLines`, it is not good for your memory and it is good practice to avoid. Try using `File.ReadLines` instead as it will return a `seq<string>`, reading the lines one-by-one into memory, not all at once.

```
for line in File.ReadLines(path) do
    … // do something with line
```

if you do not want to enumerate the line there, it still is just a `seq<string>` (which is an alias of `IEnumerable<string>`), so you can pass it to functions and code that can handle `seq`, like `Seq` Module, and you are getting good responsible memory management consuming only one row at a time, rather then loading the whole file into memory and an enormous string that will likely end up on the LOH.

To answer your question, although you should not do this

```
  if File.Exists(maincfPath) then
    let lines = File.ReadAllLines(maincfPath) // readAllLines creates line array not you
    … // use lines here (or call function that uses lines)
  else
    Environment.Exit(0)
```

As was aready given … but once again, avoid loading all lines into memory if possible.

Comment: It.you know the file is small, there's no harm in using ReadAllLines.  Perhaps the operation requires keeping the whole file in memory anyway.